# Permission for non-activity class

Tags: android, permissions

I have a public class `public class GlobalFunctions` in wich i collect some functions in order to be used from different parts of my app. I access them in a static way like `public static boolean sendSMS(String number, String message)` In my Android manifest i have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>` Tag and everything worked well.
But since api 16, i get a Security exeption, the UUID 1002 have no permission to send SMS.

I solved the problem by moving the function into my main activity, but is there a way to set permissions to non activity classes which are used in a static way?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the uses-permission tags on the same levels as the application tag.

This way your whole app will have these permissions.

Comment: my permissions are beneth the <manifest> Tag and it worked up to api lvl 15, there seemed to be a change since lvl 16